# Ubuntu 14.04 crashes on resuming from suspend

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, suspend, nouveau

Scenario.

I recently uninstalled Nvidia propitiatory drivers, and installed nouveau ones.
Before that, sleep and resume worked fine. So it might be a driver issue, but I don't want to taint my kernel again.

Problem
pm-suspend or closing the lid suspends the session, but on resuming, I am stuck at login screen. everything freezes and a hard reboot is needed to start things again.

Logs

```
Tue Aug  5 00:55:09 IST 2014: Finished.
Initial commandline parameters: 
Tue Aug  5 01:15:14 IST 2014: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux hardy 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
ppp_deflate            12950  0 
bsd_comp               12921  0 
ppp_async              17413  1 
crc_ccitt              12707  1 ppp_async
ip6table_filter        12815  0 
ip6_tables             27025  1 ip6table_filter
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23194  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             27613  0 
vboxdrv               339502  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
rfcomm                 69160  8 
bnep                   19624  2 
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46254  4 
iptable_filter         12810  0 
ipt_MASQUERADE         12880  1 
zte_ev                 13178  2 
iptable_nat            13011  1 
nf_conntrack_ipv4      15012  1 
nf_defrag_ipv4         12758  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            13263  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 21841  3 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           96976  5 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4
iptable_mangle         12695  0 
ip_tables              27239  3 iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat
x_tables               34059  6 ip6table_filter,ip_tables,ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,ip6_tables
usbserial              45014  6 zte_ev
arc4                   12608  2 
iwldvm                232285  0 
mac80211              630653  1 iwldvm
ppdev                  17671  0 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
dell_laptop            18168  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
snd_hda_codec_realtek    61438  1 
btusb                  32412  0 
bluetooth             391196  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hda_intel          52355  5 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
kvm_intel             143060  0 
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
aesni_intel            55624  0 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
joydev                 17381  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
lpc_ich                21080  0 
snd                    69238  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
soundcore              12680  1 snd
dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
nouveau              1097199  4 
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19177  3 dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  19476  1 nouveau
ttm                    85115  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         53081  1 nouveau
drm                   303102  6 ttm,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
mac_hid                13205  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 nouveau
coretemp               13435  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  2 lp,ppdev
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 52570  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
psmouse               106678  0 
ahci                   25819  3 
r8169                  67581  0 
libahci                32560  1 ahci
mii                    13934  1 r8169
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8135984    2435028    5700956      52340     154652     956940
-/+ buffers/cache:    1323436    6812548
Swap:      9764860          0    9764860
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Selected interface 'wlan0'
OK
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
stop: Unknown instance: 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Tue Aug  5 01:15:15 IST 2014: performing suspend
Tue Aug  5 01:15:29 IST 2014: Awake.
Tue Aug  5 01:15:29 IST 2014: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254

/dev/sdb:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Selected interface 'wlan0'
OK
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.
```

The Xorg logs

```
[  3167.616] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  3167.616] (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVLeaveVT is called.
[  3174.793] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[  3174.793] (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVEnterVT is called.
[  3174.831] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 709
[  3174.831] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  3174.831] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2
200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[  3174.831] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  396.36  1920 1968 2000 2
888  1080 1083 1088 1372 +hsync -vsync (137.2 kHz e)
[  3174.831] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  396.36  1920 1968 2000 2
888  1080 1083 1088 1248 +hsync -vsync (137.2 kHz e)
[  3174.831] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  396.36  1920 1968 2000 2
888  1080 1083 1088 1144 +hsync -vsync (137.2 kHz e)
[  3174.961] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
(EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing ev
ents are processed.
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7f9338f3cc78]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (mieqEnqueue+0x22b) [0x7f9338f1eceb]
(EE) 2: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x7f9338e00b12] 
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f932f4c3000+0x57fd) [0x7f93      2f4c87fd]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9338d94000+0x92e88) [0x7f9338e26e88]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9338d94000+0xbb530) [0x7f9338e4f530]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f9337e91000+0x10340) [0x7f9337
 ea1340]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (ioctl+0x7) [0x7f93369a11c7]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (drmIoctl+0x34) [0x7f9337c883a4]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (drmCommandWrite+0x1e) [0x7f9337c8
 a6be]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2 (nouveau_bo_wait+0x89) [0
 x7f9332e3f1c9]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2 (nouveau_pushbuf_space+0x
 c6) [0x7f9332e403f6]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so (0x7f9333043000+0x23859) [
 0x7f9333066859]
(EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0x7f9332a02000+0xd70f) [0x7f9332a0f70f
]
(EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0x7f9332a02000+0xe1bc) [0x7f9332a101bc
]
(EE) 15: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0x7f9332a02000+0xc028) [0x7f9332a0e028
]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9338d94000+0x1333a6) [0x7f9338ec73a6]
(EE) 17: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9338d94000+0x12988e) [0x7f9338ebd88e]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9338d94000+0x55abe) [0x7f9338de9abe]
(EE) 19: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9338d94000+0x5994a) [0x7f9338ded94a] 
(EE) 20: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f93368d0ec
5]
(EE) 21: /usr/bin/X (0x7f9338d94000+0x44e7e) [0x7f9338dd8e7e]
(EE) 
(EE) [mi] These backtraces from mieqEnqueue may point to a culprit higher up the
stack.
(EE)   [mi] mieq is *NOT* the cause.  It is a victim.
```

Comment: When your log in comes back up, are you able to move the mouse but not type? Or is it completely stuck? If you're able to move the mouse, click any of the icons in the top right of the screen, then click the password box and try typing.

Comment: nopes, its stuck. nothing works. can't switch terminal also via ctrl + alt + <F1..F5>

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't use nouveau that do not support putting the NVidia vga adapter in suspend and expect that suspend works. I'm sorry, you *have* to install the proprietary NVidia drivers to make suspend work again... see this: [nouveau driver prevents suspending, and I wouldn't even need it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031344/nouveau-driver-prevents-suspending-and-i-wouldnt-even-need-it#1031786)