# nouveau driver prevents suspending, and I wouldn't even need it

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, nouveau

I have a Dell XPS 15, with both an integrate Intel GPU and a discrete Nvidia one. I use the Nvidia X Server Settings program to set my system to use the Intel one, for power saving reasons. Regardless, the nouveau driver is loaded, and when this is the case, most times when I try to suspend, suspending fails and I just end up at the lock screen (and am able to unlock normally). Once in a blue moon it works though.

Now I would be happy with a solution that makes the nouveau drivers work with suspend, but I would also be fine with not loading them at all, since I use the Intel GPU anyway.

I'm running 18.04 and kernel 4.15.0-20.

Output of `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:141 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

If use Nvidia X Server Settings to switch to the proprietary nvidia drivers, the above changes to reflect that, and suspending works fine. (Actually that's not true, but it breaks in a different and less drastic way, and I don't care.)

I have some files in `/etc/modprobe.d/` (that I didn't create) that I would think would blacklist nouveau. Output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf`:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off

# Do not modify
# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
blacklist nvidia
blacklist nvidia-drm
blacklist nvidia-modeset
alias nvidia off
alias nvidia-drm off
alias nvidia-modeset off
```

In `/var/log/syslog`, after a failed attempt to suspend, I find the following:

```
systemd[1]: Starting TLP suspend/resume...
kernel: [  113.015159] msr: Direct access to MSR 1b0
systemd[1]: Started TLP suspend/resume.
systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
systemd-sleep[2460]: Suspending system...
kernel: [  113.045574] PM: suspend entry (deep)
kernel: [  113.045575] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
kernel: [  113.056901] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
kernel: [  113.058642] OOM killer disabled.
kernel: [  113.058643] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
kernel: [  113.059619] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
kernel: [  113.263840] psmouse serio1: Failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1
kernel: [  116.155267] ------------[ cut here ]------------
kernel: [  116.155268] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
kernel: [  116.155299] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 611 at /build/linux-5s7Xkn/linux-4.15.0/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/mmu/vmmgf100.c:207 gf100_vmm_flush_+0x15c/0x1a0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155299] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm thunderbolt msr cmac bnep arc4 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops btrtl btbcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel videobuf2_core bluetooth videodev media ecdh_generic nouveau ttm nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic dell_smbios_wmi dell_wmi wmi_bmof dell_wmi_descriptor dell_laptop mxm_wmi intel_wmi_thunderbolt dell_smbios_smm dell_smbios dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec intel_rapl ath10k_pci snd_hda_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hwdep ath10k_core snd_pcm coretemp kvm_intel snd_seq_midi ath snd_seq_midi_event kvm mac80211 snd_rawmidi snd_seq irqbypass intel_cstate snd_seq_device intel_rapl_perf snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 memstick idma64 virt_dma snd joydev input_leds
kernel: [  116.155320]  mei_me serio_raw soundcore intel_lpss_pci processor_thermal_device mei shpchp intel_pch_thermal intel_lpss intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad intel_hid wmi mac_hid tpm_crb sparse_keymap sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt usbhid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd i2c_algo_bit glue_helper cryptd drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect psmouse sysimgblt fb_sys_fops nvme drm nvme_core ahci rtsx_pci libahci i2c_hid hid video
kernel: [  116.155339] CPU: 7 PID: 611 Comm: kworker/u16:6 Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu
kernel: [  116.155340] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9560/05FFDN, BIOS 1.7.1 01/25/2018
kernel: [  116.155342] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
kernel: [  116.155358] RIP: 0010:gf100_vmm_flush_+0x15c/0x1a0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155359] RSP: 0018:ffffb7cfc23d3710 EFLAGS: 00010286
kernel: [  116.155359] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9ba8eb20ea00 RCX: ffffffffb94628a8
kernel: [  116.155360] RDX: ffffffffb94628a8 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: 0000000000000202
kernel: [  116.155361] RBP: ffffb7cfc23d3748 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000001d
kernel: [  116.155361] R10: ffffffffc0cc01e0 R11: 0000000000000620 R12: ffff9ba8e8809800
kernel: [  116.155361] R13: ffff9ba8eb7cb3c0 R14: 0000001a942e54c0 R15: ffff9ba8ae5c5a00
kernel: [  116.155362] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9ba8fe5c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
kernel: [  116.155363] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
kernel: [  116.155363] CR2: 000055d23a343286 CR3: 00000001e4a0a001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
kernel: [  116.155364] Call Trace:
kernel: [  116.155380]  gp100_vmm_flush+0x17/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155394]  nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.13+0x2e5/0x880 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155408]  ? gp100_vmm_pgt_sparse+0xd0/0xd0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155417]  ? nvkm_object_init+0xc2/0x190 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155430]  nvkm_vmm_unmap_locked+0x8a/0xc0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155442]  ? gp100_vmm_pgt_sparse+0xd0/0xd0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155454]  nvkm_uvmm_mthd+0x662/0x8d0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155463]  nvkm_object_mthd+0x1a/0x30 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155471]  nvkm_ioctl_mthd+0x5d/0xb0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155479]  nvkm_ioctl+0x11d/0x280 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155522]  nvkm_client_ioctl+0x12/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155530]  nvif_object_ioctl+0x47/0x50 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155538]  nvif_object_mthd+0x129/0x150 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155581]  ? nouveau_mem_host+0x122/0x1b0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155590]  nvif_vmm_unmap+0x3b/0x60 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155605]  nouveau_vma_unmap+0x24/0x40 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155620]  nouveau_bo_move_ntfy+0x9e/0xe0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155623]  ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0x251/0x5c0 [ttm]
kernel: [  116.155625]  ? ttm_bo_mem_space+0x39d/0x470 [ttm]
kernel: [  116.155627]  ttm_bo_evict+0x13d/0x340 [ttm]
kernel: [  116.155629]  ttm_mem_evict_first+0x159/0x1b0 [ttm]
kernel: [  116.155631]  ttm_bo_force_list_clean+0x6c/0x120 [ttm]
kernel: [  116.155633]  ttm_bo_evict_mm+0x26/0x50 [ttm]
kernel: [  116.155647]  nouveau_do_suspend+0x81/0x2c0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155661]  nouveau_pmops_suspend+0x39/0x80 [nouveau]
kernel: [  116.155663]  pci_pm_suspend+0x8c/0x150
kernel: [  116.155665]  dpm_run_callback+0x5a/0x150
kernel: [  116.155666]  ? pci_pm_resume+0xb0/0xb0
kernel: [  116.155667]  __device_suspend+0x126/0x450
kernel: [  116.155668]  async_suspend+0x1f/0xa0
kernel: [  116.155669]  async_run_entry_fn+0x3c/0x150
kernel: [  116.155670]  process_one_work+0x1de/0x410
kernel: [  116.155671]  worker_thread+0x32/0x410
kernel: [  116.155673]  kthread+0x121/0x140
kernel: [  116.155674]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
kernel: [  116.155675]  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
kernel: [  116.155677]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
kernel: [  116.155677] Code: 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 49 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 47 e8 86 39 a2 f7 48 89 da 48 89 c6 48 c7 c7 28 47 d1 c0 e8 a4 bb 46 f7 <0f> 0b eb bf 49 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 24 e8 5d 39 
kernel: [  116.155693] ---[ end trace 3ca36c17fb64f8b9 ]---
kernel: [  118.156703] ------------[ cut here ]------------
kernel: [  118.156703] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
kernel: [  118.156735] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 611 at /build/linux-5s7Xkn/linux-4.15.0/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/mmu/vmmgf100.c:207 gf100_vmm_flush_+0x15c/0x1a0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156736] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm thunderbolt msr cmac bnep arc4 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops btrtl btbcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel videobuf2_core bluetooth videodev media ecdh_generic nouveau ttm nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic dell_smbios_wmi dell_wmi wmi_bmof dell_wmi_descriptor dell_laptop mxm_wmi intel_wmi_thunderbolt dell_smbios_smm dell_smbios dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec intel_rapl ath10k_pci snd_hda_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hwdep ath10k_core snd_pcm coretemp kvm_intel snd_seq_midi ath snd_seq_midi_event kvm mac80211 snd_rawmidi snd_seq irqbypass intel_cstate snd_seq_device intel_rapl_perf snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 memstick idma64 virt_dma snd joydev input_leds
kernel: [  118.156751]  mei_me serio_raw soundcore intel_lpss_pci processor_thermal_device mei shpchp intel_pch_thermal intel_lpss intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad intel_hid wmi mac_hid tpm_crb sparse_keymap sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt usbhid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd i2c_algo_bit glue_helper cryptd drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect psmouse sysimgblt fb_sys_fops nvme drm nvme_core ahci rtsx_pci libahci i2c_hid hid video
kernel: [  118.156765] CPU: 3 PID: 611 Comm: kworker/u16:6 Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu
kernel: [  118.156766] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9560/05FFDN, BIOS 1.7.1 01/25/2018
kernel: [  118.156767] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
kernel: [  118.156782] RIP: 0010:gf100_vmm_flush_+0x15c/0x1a0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156782] RSP: 0018:ffffb7cfc23d3540 EFLAGS: 00010286
kernel: [  118.156783] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9ba8eb20ea00 RCX: ffffffffb94628a8
kernel: [  118.156784] RDX: ffffffffb94628a8 RSI: 0000000000000086 RDI: 0000000000000202
kernel: [  118.156784] RBP: ffffb7cfc23d3578 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000001d
kernel: [  118.156785] R10: ffffffffc0c136d0 R11: 000000000000065a R12: ffff9ba8e8809800
kernel: [  118.156785] R13: ffff9ba8eb7cb3c0 R14: 0000001b0b7aeb40 R15: ffff9ba8e524e400
kernel: [  118.156786] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9ba8fe4c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
kernel: [  118.156786] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
kernel: [  118.156787] CR2: 0000556f80622ec6 CR3: 00000001e4a0a001 CR4: 00000000003606e0
kernel: [  118.156787] Call Trace:
kernel: [  118.156802]  gp100_vmm_flush+0x17/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156816]  nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.13+0x2e5/0x880 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156818]  ? down_trylock+0x2e/0x40
kernel: [  118.156831]  ? gp100_vmm_pgt_sgl+0x180/0x180 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156844]  ? nvkm_vmm_map_choose+0xb0/0xb0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156845]  ? vprintk_emit+0x326/0x3a0
kernel: [  118.156846]  ? vprintk_default+0x29/0x50
kernel: [  118.156859]  nvkm_vmm_map+0x21e/0x400 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156871]  ? gp100_vmm_pgt_sgl+0x180/0x180 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156872]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
kernel: [  118.156884]  nvkm_vram_map+0x57/0x80 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156897]  nvkm_uvmm_mthd+0x792/0x8d0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156906]  nvkm_object_mthd+0x1a/0x30 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156914]  nvkm_ioctl_mthd+0x5d/0xb0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156922]  nvkm_ioctl+0x11d/0x280 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156938]  nvkm_client_ioctl+0x12/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156946]  nvif_object_ioctl+0x47/0x50 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156953]  nvif_object_mthd+0x129/0x150 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156969]  ? nv50_grctx_generate+0xbd0/0x16e0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156971]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x40
kernel: [  118.156972]  ? __kmalloc+0x18e/0x220
kernel: [  118.156980]  nvif_vmm_map+0x88/0xb0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.156996]  nouveau_mem_map+0x88/0xf0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.157011]  nouveau_bo_move_m2mf.constprop.24+0x1a3/0x1d0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.157025]  nouveau_bo_move+0xab/0x440 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.157033]  ? nvif_vmm_unmap+0x3b/0x60 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.157047]  ? nouveau_vma_unmap+0x24/0x40 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.157050]  ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0x29f/0x5c0 [ttm]
kernel: [  118.157052]  ? ttm_bo_mem_space+0x39d/0x470 [ttm]
kernel: [  118.157054]  ttm_bo_evict+0x13d/0x340 [ttm]
kernel: [  118.157056]  ttm_mem_evict_first+0x159/0x1b0 [ttm]
kernel: [  118.157058]  ttm_bo_force_list_clean+0x6c/0x120 [ttm]
kernel: [  118.157059]  ttm_bo_evict_mm+0x26/0x50 [ttm]
kernel: [  118.157073]  nouveau_do_suspend+0x81/0x2c0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.157087]  nouveau_pmops_suspend+0x39/0x80 [nouveau]
kernel: [  118.157088]  pci_pm_suspend+0x8c/0x150
kernel: [  118.157089]  dpm_run_callback+0x5a/0x150
kernel: [  118.157090]  ? pci_pm_resume+0xb0/0xb0
kernel: [  118.157091]  __device_suspend+0x126/0x450
kernel: [  118.157092]  async_suspend+0x1f/0xa0
kernel: [  118.157093]  async_run_entry_fn+0x3c/0x150
kernel: [  118.157094]  process_one_work+0x1de/0x410
kernel: [  118.157095]  worker_thread+0x32/0x410
kernel: [  118.157096]  kthread+0x121/0x140
kernel: [  118.157097]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
kernel: [  118.157098]  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
kernel: [  118.157099]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
kernel: [  118.157100] Code: 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 49 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 47 e8 86 39 a2 f7 48 89 da 48 89 c6 48 c7 c7 28 47 d1 c0 e8 a4 bb 46 f7 <0f> 0b eb bf 49 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 24 e8 5d 39 
kernel: [  118.157116] ---[ end trace 3ca36c17fb64f8ba ]---
kernel: [  120.157961] ------------[ cut here ]------------
kernel: [  120.157962] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
.
. the same kind of crap repeated multiple times
.
kernel: [  140.182517] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 0 [DRM] kick timeout
kernel: [  140.182520] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 0: killed
kernel: [  140.182521] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
kernel: [  140.182525] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 7: scheduled for recovery
kernel: [  140.182527] nouveau: DRM:00000000:0000c06f: detach ce0 failed, -110
kernel: [  140.182528] nouveau: DRM:0004c1b5:0000c1b5: suspend failed with -110
kernel: [  140.182531] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: channel 0 killed!
kernel: [  140.182618] pci_pm_suspend(): nouveau_pmops_suspend+0x0/0x80 [nouveau] returns -110
kernel: [  140.182620] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -110
kernel: [  140.182622] PM: Device 0000:01:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -110
kernel: [  140.182737] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
kernel: [  140.184000] ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
kernel: [  140.558982] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
kernel: [  140.683376] acpi LNXPOWER:16: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.683519] acpi LNXPOWER:15: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.683655] acpi LNXPOWER:14: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.683790] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.683924] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.684058] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.684190] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.684324] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.684459] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.684592] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.684726] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.684860] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.684995] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.685128] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.685264] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.685398] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.685532] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.685666] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.685800] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.685933] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
kernel: [  140.686032] OOM killer enabled.
kernel: [  140.686033] Restarting tasks ... 
kernel: [  140.687401] [drm] RC6 on
kernel: [  140.688963] done.
rtkit-daemon[1207]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Demoting known real-time threads.
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Successfully demoted thread 1814 of process 1806 (n/a).
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Successfully demoted thread 1813 of process 1806 (n/a).
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Successfully demoted thread 1806 of process 1806 (n/a).
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Demoted 3 threads.
kernel: [  140.720271] PM: suspend exit
kernel: [  140.720299] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
kernel: [  140.720300] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
kernel: [  140.734445] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
kernel: [  140.736143] OOM killer disabled.
kernel: [  140.736144] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.128 seconds) done.
kernel: [  140.865009] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
kernel: [  149.147400] psmouse serio1: Failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1
kernel: [  151.838519] ------------[ cut here ]------------
kernel: [  151.838520] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
kernel: [  151.838550] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 2498 at /build/linux-5s7Xkn/linux-4.15.0/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/mmu/vmmgf100.c:207 gf100_vmm_flush_+0x15c/0x1a0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838551] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm thunderbolt msr cmac bnep arc4 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops btrtl btbcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel videobuf2_core bluetooth videodev media ecdh_generic nouveau ttm nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic dell_smbios_wmi dell_wmi wmi_bmof dell_wmi_descriptor dell_laptop mxm_wmi intel_wmi_thunderbolt dell_smbios_smm dell_smbios dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec intel_rapl ath10k_pci snd_hda_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hwdep ath10k_core snd_pcm coretemp kvm_intel snd_seq_midi ath snd_seq_midi_event kvm mac80211 snd_rawmidi snd_seq irqbypass intel_cstate snd_seq_device intel_rapl_perf snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 memstick idma64 virt_dma snd joydev input_leds
kernel: [  151.838572]  mei_me serio_raw soundcore intel_lpss_pci processor_thermal_device mei shpchp intel_pch_thermal intel_lpss intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad intel_hid wmi mac_hid tpm_crb sparse_keymap sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt usbhid rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd i2c_algo_bit glue_helper cryptd drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect psmouse sysimgblt fb_sys_fops nvme drm nvme_core ahci rtsx_pci libahci i2c_hid hid video
kernel: [  151.838591] CPU: 5 PID: 2498 Comm: kworker/u16:40 Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu
kernel: [  151.838591] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9560/05FFDN, BIOS 1.7.1 01/25/2018
kernel: [  151.838594] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
kernel: [  151.838609] RIP: 0010:gf100_vmm_flush_+0x15c/0x1a0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838610] RSP: 0000:ffffb7cfc39b7830 EFLAGS: 00010282
kernel: [  151.838611] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9ba8eb20ea00 RCX: ffffffffb94628a8
kernel: [  151.838612] RDX: ffffffffb94628a8 RSI: 0000000000000082 RDI: 0000000000000202
kernel: [  151.838612] RBP: ffffb7cfc39b7868 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000001d
kernel: [  151.838613] R10: ffffffffc0c136d0 R11: 00000000000009a5 R12: ffff9ba8e8809800
kernel: [  151.838613] R13: ffff9ba8eb7cb3c0 R14: 00000022e315a340 R15: ffff9ba8e524e000
kernel: [  151.838614] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9ba8fe540000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
kernel: [  151.838614] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
kernel: [  151.838615] CR2: 00007f374fbba508 CR3: 00000001e4a0a005 CR4: 00000000003606e0
kernel: [  151.838615] Call Trace:
kernel: [  151.838632]  gp100_vmm_flush+0x17/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838645]  nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.13+0x2e5/0x880 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838659]  ? gp100_vmm_pgt_sgl+0x180/0x180 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838671]  ? nvkm_vmm_map_choose+0xb0/0xb0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838684]  nvkm_vmm_map+0x21e/0x400 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838696]  ? gp100_vmm_pgt_sgl+0x180/0x180 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838708]  nvkm_vram_map+0x57/0x80 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838721]  nv50_instobj_map+0x19/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838729]  nvkm_gpuobj_heap_map+0x19/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838744]  gm200_secboot_run_blob+0xa4/0x1c0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838758]  gp102_secboot_run_blob+0x1d9/0x2e0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838759]  ? flush_work+0x5b/0x1e0
kernel: [  151.838761]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x40
kernel: [  151.838775]  acr_r352_shutdown+0x47/0x150 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838787]  acr_r352_fini+0xe/0x10 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838799]  gm200_secboot_fini+0x29/0x30 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838811]  nvkm_secboot_fini+0x23/0x30 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838820]  nvkm_subdev_fini+0x5f/0x150 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838834]  nvkm_device_fini+0x87/0x1c0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838848]  nvkm_udevice_fini+0x53/0x70 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838857]  nvkm_object_fini+0xbd/0x220 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838865]  nvkm_object_fini+0x78/0x220 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838882]  nvkm_client_suspend+0x13/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838890]  nvif_client_suspend+0x1d/0x20 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838906]  nouveau_do_suspend+0x1a0/0x2c0 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838920]  nouveau_pmops_suspend+0x39/0x80 [nouveau]
kernel: [  151.838922]  pci_pm_suspend+0x8c/0x150
kernel: [  151.838924]  dpm_run_callback+0x5a/0x150
kernel: [  151.838925]  ? pci_pm_resume+0xb0/0xb0
kernel: [  151.838926]  __device_suspend+0x126/0x450
kernel: [  151.838927]  async_suspend+0x1f/0xa0
kernel: [  151.838928]  async_run_entry_fn+0x3c/0x150
kernel: [  151.838929]  process_one_work+0x1de/0x410
kernel: [  151.838930]  worker_thread+0x32/0x410
kernel: [  151.838931]  kthread+0x121/0x140
kernel: [  151.838932]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
kernel: [  151.838933]  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
kernel: [  151.838935]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
kernel: [  151.838935] Code: 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 49 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 47 e8 86 39 a2 f7 48 89 da 48 89 c6 48 c7 c7 28 47 d1 c0 e8 a4 bb 46 f7 <0f> 0b eb bf 49 8b 7c 24 10 48 8b 5f 50 48 85 db 74 24 e8 5d 39 
kernel: [  151.838951] ---[ end trace 3ca36c17fb64f8c6 ]---
.
. a few more times the same timeout what-not blahblah
.
kernel: [  153.861931] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: secboot: suspend failed, -110
kernel: [  153.861957] nouveau: DRM-master:00000000:00000080: suspend failed with -110
kernel: [  153.862060] pci_pm_suspend(): nouveau_pmops_suspend+0x0/0x80 [nouveau] returns -110
kernel: [  153.862062] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -110
kernel: [  153.862064] PM: Device 0000:01:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -110
kernel: [  154.159403] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
kernel: [  154.332079] OOM killer enabled.
kernel: [  154.332080] Restarting tasks ... done.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1640]: (EE) client bug: timer event7 keyboard: offset negative (-12669ms)
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1640]: (EE) client bug: timer event12 keyboard: offset negative (-12669ms)
rtkit-daemon[1207]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Demoting known real-time threads.
systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Successfully demoted thread 1814 of process 1806 (n/a).
systemd[1]: Failed to start Suspend.
kernel: [  154.384596] PM: suspend exit
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Successfully demoted thread 1813 of process 1806 (n/a).
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Suspend.
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Successfully demoted thread 1806 of process 1806 (n/a).
systemd[1]: suspend.target: Job suspend.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
rtkit-daemon[1207]: Demoted 3 threads.
systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
systemd[1]: tlp-sleep.service: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
systemd[1]: Stopping TLP suspend/resume...
```

The same `/var/log/syslog` includes similar complaints with `nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout` and all that at every boot. On the rare occasion that suspending succeeds, the log is missing all this crap about nouveau.

Any pointers for how to fix the issue (great) or disable nouveau (good)? Why don't the `/etc/modprobe.d/` blacklist files prevent the loading of the whole driver? How would I manually go about unloading it? (I tried `modprobe -r` to no great success.)

Comment: I have had similar issues.  Eventually gave up on Nouveau.

Comment: By that you mean you now always run on the discrete GPU using the proprietary drivers? If you found a way of killing nouveau and resorting to Intel, I'm interested.

Comment: Come to think of it, I could try using bumblebee, in which case it would probably load the proprietary drivers for the Nvidia card and still allow me to actually use the Intel one. I'll try that once I have the time, if I don't come up with anything else.

Comment: Found a couple of old, possibly related issues, will have to investigate if these are duplicates and/or helpful:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/510741/failed-to-suspend-due-to-nouveau-failure?rq=1
https://askubuntu.com/questions/473214/laptop-suspend-broken-after-latest-kernel-update

Comment: I've had the same problem and I've found multiple nouveau bug reports related to this issue over the past few years - some are even marked as fixed, even if it really isn't. I'm guessing it's something that breaks again with each new card or something stupid like that.

Comment: 19.04 help by chance?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by installing bumblebee, which took over managing which drivers to load. It now loads the proprietary nvidia driver for my discrete GPU, and so suspending works, and I'm still not burning through my battery and eardrums, because bumblebee defaults to using the Intel GPU unless requested otherwise.

Not the greatest solution, more a work-around, so feel free to post something better. I got what I wanted though, and feel lazy to investigate further.

Comment: I fixed it the same way, but my issue is that always running the nvidia card wastes battery.

Answer (score 1):

since this question is the first result searching for `pci_pm_suspend(): nouveau_pmops_suspend+0x0/0x80 [nouveau] returns -16` (+ `dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -16` + `PM: Device 0000:01:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -16`), I would like to point to another one : [Kubuntu 18.04 wakes immediately after suspend (unable to suspend)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081531/kubuntu-18-04-wakes-immediately-after-suspend-unable-to-suspend)

Note I add this error only after the first hibernation, then I need to restart to make hibernation work again.

Adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` made hibernation work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of issues with sleep, depending on kernel version, driver version (also between nvidia versions) and other software.

I suggest to check : /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ for suspicious software that may interfere with sleep.

In my case, it was either hdparm or ltp.
Also, I believe an Nvidia driver before 4.70 leaves links that break sleep.

I never had sleep working with the Nvidia driver, I currently use the latest Ubuntu 22.04 on kernel 5.15.0.22 , nouveau driver, Wayland and the 5.5 displaylink driver and sleep seems to work now - quite sure it was hdparm messing up mine ( which I removed because I have SSD disks only ).

I have a Dell Inspiron 5482, so I have this in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

to make sure deep sleep is used and not S3.